# .htaccess redirect rule to remove specific part from url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have to do 301 redirection for all my url's something from

```
http://www.example.com.au/website-blog/item/121-itemName
```

to

```
http://www.example.com.au/website-blog/itemName
```

Need to remove part `item/(itemId)-` from all urls.

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^item/[\d]+-(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA].
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What king of platform you run on the website? Is this platform redirect all requests (except existing files) to certain file like index.php

Comment: I removed the "^" and your regex seemed to work correctly on regexpal.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the item name using `(.+)` and substitute accordingly. Place the following rule in `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^website-blog/item/\d+-(.+) /website-blog/$1 [R,L]
```

Note:

- Change `R` to `R=301` after testing
- The `QSA` flag is not required in this case